# customize kibana histogram

Tags: histogram, kibana

I have a set of data that I need to display on kibana as a histogram.

Let the set of strings A and B lets call it Locks and Keys respectively, where multiple Keys can unlock a single lock so there is an association with it. Each keys has different length and that is what I need to show in histogram. For instances, there can be 4keys with length 5cm and 2 keys with length 2cm.

How can I customize kibana to make the x-axis being the length and y-axis being the count?

Much appreciated for any suggestion provided.

Answer (score 2):

Histograms are for time series data.  You probably want a [term panel](http://www.elasticsearch.org/videos/introduction-kibana-terms-panel/).